# in Asp.net while creating the model can I modify the datatype string to int without lossing my old data?

Tags: .net, crud

In asp .Net while creating the model in the database I want to update the datatype string to the int in the column without deleting my old data

I want to know the details about it while updating the database in the given type i want to know the what all are the command i should use in the given command

Comment: Are you asking about schema migrations? So how to change the type of a column without losing information in existing rows?

Comment: I want to update in my model where the given datatype can be change from string to the integer in the column by using the command in the package manager console

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you using EF? And if so are you talking about Code-First migrations?

Comment: yes .In the code first approach how can edit my  datatype in model by string to int without deleting my old data